# Tips on improving this function?

Tags: python, math, polygon

This may be quite a green question, but I hope you understand – just started on python and trying to improve. Anyways, wrote a little function to do the "Shoelace Method" of finding the area of a polygon in a Cartesian plane (see [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoelace_formula) for a refresher).

I want to know how can I improve my method, so I can try out fancy new ways of doing the same old things.

```
    def shoelace(list):
        r_p     = 0         # Positive Values
        r_n     = 0         # Negative Values

        x, y    = [i[0] for i in list], [i[1] for i in list]
        x.append(x[0]), y.append(y[0])

        print(x, y)

        for i in range(len(x)):
            if (i+1) < len(x):
                r_p += (x[i] * y[i+1])
                r_n += (x[i+1] * y[i])
            else:
                break

        return ((abs(r_p - r_n))/2)
```

Comment: You should post this on the code review SE site.

Comment: One tip: `list` is a bad name for a variable as it is the name of a built-in.

Answer (score 2):

- Don't use short variable names that need to be commented; use names that indicate the function.
- `list` is the name of the built-in list type, so while Python will let you replace that name, it's a bad idea stylistically.
- `,` should not be used to separate what are supposed to be statements. You can use `;`, but it's generally better to just put things on separate lines. In your case, it happens to work because you are using `.append` for the side effect, but basically what you are doing is constructing the 2-tuple `(None, None)` (the return values from `.append`) and throwing it away.
- Use built-in functions where possible for standard list transformations. See the documentation for `zip`, for example. Except you don't really need to perform this transformation; you want to consider pairs of adjacent points, so do that - and take apart their coordinates inside the loop.
- However, you *can* use `zip` to transform the list of points into a list of pairs-of-adjacent-points :) which lets you write a much cleaner loop. The idea is simple: first, we make a list of all the "next" points relative to the originals, and then we `zip` the two point-lists together.
- `return` is not a function, so the thing you're `return`ing does not need surrounding parentheses.
- Instead of tallying up separate positive and negative values, perform signed arithmetic on a single value.

---

```
def shoelace(points):
    signed_double_area = 0

    next_points = points[1:] + points[:1]

    for begin, end in zip(points, next_points):
        begin_x, begin_y = begin
        end_x, end_y = end
        signed_double_area += begin_x * end_y
        signed_double_area -= end_x * begin_y

    return abs(signed_double_area) / 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Functionally, your program is quite good. One minor remark is to replace `range(len(x))` with `xrange(len(x))`. It makes the program slightly more efficient. Generally, you should use `range` only in cases where you actually need the full list of values it creates. If all you need is to loop over those values, use `xrange`.

Also, you don't need the parenthesis in the `return` statement, nor in the `r_p +=` and `r_n +=` statements.

Regarding style, in Python variable assignments shouldn't be done like you did, but rather with a single space on each side of the `=` symbol:

```
r_p = 0
r_n = 0
```

Comment: You're welcome. Make sure you don't miss Burhan's suggestion, which I missed (Monday morning): `list` is a terrible name for a variable.